# How to enable response logging in standalone wiremock

Tags: rest, wiremock

How to enable verbose **response**  logging in standalone wiremock?

Thks

Answer (score 1):

In the current latest version `2.11.0`. You can do it in this way

```
 WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(new WireMockConfiguration().port(8080).notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true)));
    wireMockServer.start();
    wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/get/user/1000"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                    .withBodyFile("user.json")));
```

You need to keep the body json file in `src/test/resources/__files/` directory

Answer (score 0):

The --verbose CLI flag will do this in the 2.x versions.

Unfortunately this isn't possible in 1.x.